# Unresolved externals when using Synapse (internet access) on C++Builder XE5

Tags: c++, linker, c++builder, apache-synapse, c++builder-xe5

I have some troubles with linking (Ararat) Synapse library on my new C++Builder XE5.
Before that I used C++Builder XE2 and everything was OK.
Now I've created a new project with C++Builder XE5 and added some code on simple button click event handler method.
The code:

**Unit1.h**

```
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <blcksock.hpp>
#include <httpsend.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TMemo *Memo1;
    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
```

**Unit1.cpp**

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    THTTPSend *client = new THTTPSend();
}
```

Now I got 2 link errors:

```
Unresolved external 'Httpsend::THTTPSend::' referenced from ...\UNIT1.OBJ
Unresolved external '__fastcall Httpsend::THTTPSend::THTTPSend()' referenced from ...\UNIT1.OBJ
```

*In project options I included a directory with Synapse files*

How this errors can be resolved???

*Here is the link to Synapse sources I'm using: http://filetonet.com/AAA124f20433ab06682a1443633d799fa5b or http://yadi.sk/d/UKJKR2hoHtD9q*

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to simply point the project to Synapse's directory. You have to actually add the Synapse library/source file(s) to your project.

Comment: I've also tried this but nothing changed. (If I'm wrong please, give me actual steps to achieve proper linkage)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of troubles I added some required .pas files to my project and then put modified synsock.hpp to project directory and a line #include "synsock.hpp" before including blcksock.hpp and httpsend.hpp. Now everything linking just fine but this is terrible...